# Springboot session not maintaining for remote calls

Tags: jquery, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, session

I have an application in which I store userDto in session to use later. Then in filter I check if user not exist in session then throw 401 error. Problem is when I use localhost in my react application to access this machine it works fine and session is good. But when someone call api from another system remotely then it creates a new session every time and does not maintain the old session.

```
        
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest servReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            
            String origin = servReq.getHeader("Origin");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            String url = servReq.getRequestURL().toString();
            if (url != null
                    && (url.contains("login") || url.contains("swagger") || url.contains(AppConstants.BYPASS_API_PREFIX) || url.contains("api-docs") || url.contains("Signup") || !url.contains(AppConstants.REST_API_PREFIX))) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                System.out.println(((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getId());
                RestResponse rr = (RestResponse) servReq.getSession().getAttribute(AppConstants.SESSION_ATTR_NAME_APPLICANT);
                if (rr != null && rr.getResult() != null) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    RestResponse resp = new RestResponse(AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_UNAUTHORIZED, AppConstants.RESPONSE_CODE_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_UNAUTHORIZED, null);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(resp));
                }
            }
        }
```

When I access from localhost following are the id print in else section of above code:

```
2022-01-17 16:14:03.035  INFO 6864 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] c.w.c.service.AsyncBackgroundService     : Total time taken: 4 miliseconds
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
9C117490F2BD891E0026F657FF84F8EB
2022-01-17 16:15:25.578 ERROR 6864 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] c.w.c.service.AsyncBackgroundService
```

following are the ids from remote address like someone of my team access it using my ip address (192.168.100.124:8080)

```
2022-01-17 16:15:25.578  INFO 6864 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] c.w.c.service.AsyncBackgroundService     : Total time taken: 3 miliseconds
F2158BB4B35BA8CE730B0938A4CE8CF7
E04B8C00F60C2BE06CA641017C0C8D68
6C25C7DD04D205F0925FB4CDDDE34904
1DAEAF1E2E206C13AC720419F213974B
DB27277BAC4F4B8C657A16C33D299200
2022-01-17 16:16:20.448 ERROR 6864 ---
```

From react calling api using following method:

```
export async function checkIn() {
  const requestOptions = { method: "GET", credentials: "include" };
  const response = await fetch(
    prefixApi() + "attendance/checkIn",
    requestOptions
  ).then(handleResponse);
  const json = await response;
  return json;
}
```

any solution?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried calling by jquery but jquery has the same problem

```
<script>
      function onLoginClick() {
        let postData = {
          email: "abc@gmail.com",
          password: "123456",
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://192.168.200.64:9091/rest_api/users/login",
          data: JSON.stringify(postData),
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
        });
      }
      function onTodayClick() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://192.168.200.64:9091/rest_api/attendance/getTodaysAttendance",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true,
          },
        });
      }
```

Comment: How are they calling your API? Are they properly setting the COOKIEs you application is setting? Usually, if you are writring an API, you don't want to use HTTP SESSIONS to store anything.

Comment: updated code for react calling as well. We use login to store user. Then on marking checkin we dont take userId but get user id from session and mark user attendance.